# Calculating length of curved line derived from intersection between two polygons using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, intersection, arcgis-10.4, length

I'm trying to get the density of intersection points along their related ellipse. What I'm missing is the length of the arc of the ellipses comprised in between the yellow polygon (which is a landslide deposit).

I would need help about step by step algorithm to calculate the distance between two points along a curved line.

[image: martian landslide]

Comment: You need to provide your code in the question.

Comment: 1) Are you looking for the length of this arc: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSNDJ.jpg

Comment: 2) Do you need step by step algorithm as an answer or python code?

Comment: @Mr.Che Yes exactly! In other forums, I've found reference to the expression !shape.length@meters! but I have no idea how to apply it nor whether is a correct syntax.

Comment: @GiuliaMagna Do you need step by step algorithm or python code? I could help with algorithm but not the code.

Comment: @Mr.Che My piece of code works perfectly until creating and counting intersection points. After that I don't know how to calculate the length of purple arcs within the landslide deposit. I don't actually need help with the code  but rather with learning how to  calculate the distance between two points along a curved trajectory

Comment: @GiuliaMagna Ok. I have an answer for you. Edit your question, ask for an step by step algorithm as an answer. Ask for moderators to release your question so i able to answer.

Comment: @PolyGeo I edited my question asking for a step by step algorithm as an answer, I hope I did it right. Mr. Che will be able to answer

Comment: I'll re-open on this occasion but asking for a step by step algorithm really is not the best way to achieve that.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: @PolyGeo I don't want to do anything that is not supposed to. I thought I described my problem in the first place, explaining what I'm trying to do and where I'm stuck. I read the instructions and included an image for a better understanding. I'm new here and I'm trying to do things properly, following instructions I receive. If asking for a step by step algorithm is not the best way, then sorry, that's what I have been suggested. Apologise if my conduct  is not perfect. I'll look for the answer where is more appropriate then, sorry

Comment: There's no need to look elsewhere.  We just have a very focussed way of asking questions.  I think you should just review https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/framing-asking-good-questions-for-gis-stack-exchange to get a bit more of a feel for the site's protocols ready for when you wish next to ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Input data:

1. `Polygon_1` - random polygon (green color on the images).
2. `Polygon_2` - polygonal ellipses (red color on the images).

Step by step algorithm:

1. Use tool `Polygon To Line` to convert `Polygon_2` polygons to lines. Output data: `Line_2`
2. Use tool `Delete Identical` with data from previous step `Line_2` with `fields` parameter as `SHAPE`. (There are a lot of identical lines after previous step).
3. Use tool `Erase` to delete features from `Line_2` with `erase_features` parameter as `Polygon_1`. Output data: `Line_2_Erase_1`
4. Use tool `Erase` to delete features from `Line_2` with `erase_features` parameter as `Line_2_Erase_1`. Output data: `Line_2_Erase_2`
5. Use tool `Multipart To Singlepart` to convert `Line_2_Erase_2`. Output data: `Line_2_Erase_2_singlepart`.
6. Use tool `Unsplit Line` to convert `Line_2_Erase_2_singlepart`.
7. If your vector data stored in geodatabase - use values in field `SHAPE_Length` as length of your curves.

or if your data is in shp format you have to a) create new field and b) calculate features length using this python code:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management("Line_2_Erase_2_singlepart", "fieldName", "!shape.length@meters!", "PYTHON_9.3")
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Just wonder, step5 (Multipart To Singlepart) and step6 (Unsplit Line) are for the cases where lines intersect multiple times the polygon, aren't they? (for instance, in your image, the external ellipse intersects 3 times the polygon) In the case my ellipses intersect the polygon only once I can skip that, isn't it?

Comment: I do not recommend you to skip these steps (results may be incorrect). But you can try at your own risk . BTW don't forget to accept answer if it is what you need.